Loading HTML from variable name as page content in SvelteKit
How can I load an HTML, in a SvelteKit project, using the [slug] param as the page name?
I have a pretty simple SvelteKit project with some basic data loading. The structure (relevant to the question) of the project looks like this:
src
  lib
    cms
      projects
        slug1.html
        slug2.html
  routes
    projects
      [slug]
        +page.server.svelte
        +page.svelte

When the user visits https://example.com/projects/slug1 I'd like to load the slug1.html contents and display it as the page's contents.
In +page.server.js I have the following:
/** @type {import ('./$types').PageServerLoad } */
export async function load({ params }) {
  console.log(params);
  return {
    project: await import(`../../../lib/cms/projects/${params.slug}.html?raw`),
  };
}

My goal is to then have {@html data.project} available to me in +page.svelte. This isn't working out the way I'd hoped though, and I'm getting the following error:
Error: Data returned from `load` while rendering /projects/[slug] is not serializable: Cannot stringify POJOs with symbolic keys (data.project)
    at get_data (/Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/render.js:592:9)
    at Module.render_response (/Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/render.js:264:27)
    at async Module.render_page (/Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/index.js:286:10)
    at async resolve (/Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:446:18)
    at async Module.respond (/Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:319:20)
    at async file:///Users/me/Documents/Repositories/site/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:524:22

I'm missing an understanding of a concept for loading the data properly. How can I properly load the slug1.html contents to have available?

This is because of the format things are importing in. You can change the code to grab the default of the import instead:
return {
    project: (await import(`../../lib/cms/${params.slug}.html?raw`)).default,
};

